# How to transition out?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

For the following code, the animation on hover works fine. Once I move away, it snaps back to the original size. How do I implement a transition on loss of focus so that there is animation into the div and out?

```
<style>
.border {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:500px;
}
.changesize:hover{
    width:250px;
    transition-property: width;
    transition-duration: 1000ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}
</style>
<div class="border changesize">-- a div --</div>
```

http://scratchpad.io/caring-bead-826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following style (for .changesize when not hovered)

```
.changesize {
    transition-property: width;
    transition-duration: 1000ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}
```